Eslint 9 with typescript and vue error on defineEmits
after upgrading the dependencies of my astro blog, I've stumbled across a strange problem with the newest eslint version and typescript + vue.
I followed the official docs of eslint, tslint, eslint-plugin-vue and eslint-config-prettier, however something is strange and I don't know why.
Eslint is telling me that this codeblock has a parsing error Parsing error: Unexpected token, however this should be ok (see the official vue docs)
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'change', id: number): void
  (e: 'update', value: string): void
}>()
</script>

I've provided a minimal example https://github.com/Theiaz/eslint-defineemits-bug for the error. Seems like the config for vue is not loaded correctly. What am I missing here?
{
  "name": "typescript-eslint-vue",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "check": "vue-tsc --noEmit && tsc --noEmit ",
    "lint": "eslint --fix src"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.13.0",
    "@types/eslint__js": "^8.42.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint": "^9.13.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.10.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "vue": "^3.5.12",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.1",
    "@vueuse/core": "^11.1.0"
  }
}

import eslint from "@eslint/js";
import prettierConfig from "eslint-config-prettier";
import pluginVue from "eslint-plugin-vue";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";

export default tseslint.config(
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  ...pluginVue.configs["flat/recommended"],
  prettierConfig,
  {
    files: ["**/*.ts", "**/*.vue"],
    rules: {},
  }
);


Please, add package.json and eslint config to the question, it needs to be understandable without the need to navigate to the repo

I've provided the files

The current config misses the configuration of Vue ELint parser, as suggested in the documentation:
import vueParser from 'vue-eslint-parser';

export default tseslint.config(
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  ...pluginVue.configs["flat/recommended"],
  prettierConfig,
  {
    files: ["**/*.ts", "**/*.vue"],
    rules: {},
    languageOptions: {
      parser: vueParser,
      parserOptions: {
        parser: {
          ts: tseslint.parser,
  ...

@vue/eslint-config-typescript can be used to correctly configure ESlint to work with TypeScript and Vue SFC:
import pluginVue from "eslint-plugin-vue";
import vueTsEslintConfig from "@vue/eslint-config-typescript";

export default [
  ...pluginVue.configs["flat/essential"],
  ...vueTsEslintConfig(),
  // Add prettier or else
]

This eliminates the need to use typescript-eslint directly and provides sensible defaults.

I've seen this already, however the docs of it says "This config is specifically designed to be used by create-vue setups and is not meant for outside use". So i think there should be another way. Especially if i want to use typescript together with other environments in my astro site?

I believe this is a disclaimer, there's nothing that ties it to create-vue besides it's used there. I updated the post for clarity

Thanks for your response, this does solve my problem!
